# @Producer annotation in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I am learning Java EE CDI, dependency injection, and `@Produces` in particular. I am wondering why in `getGreedingCard()` method, it needs a `@Produces` annotation at all, since the two classes `GreetingCardImpl` and `AnotherGreetingCardImpl` are already imported into the space. This is just like the regular package/class dependency and a simple import solves the problem. Why does it need a dependency injection through a `@producer` annotation?

Thanks for explanation in advance.

```
public interface GreetingCard {
    void sayHello();
}


public class GreetingCardImpl implements GreetingCard {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!!!");
    }
}


public class AnotherGreetingCardImpl implements GreetingCard {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!!!");
    }
}

import com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.cdibeans.impl.AnotherGreetingCardImpl;
import com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.cdibeans.impl.GreetingCardImpl;

@SessionScoped
public class GreetingCardFactory implements Serializable {

    private GreetingType greetingType;

    @Produces
    public GreetingCard getGreetingCard() {
        switch (greetingType) {
            case HELLO:
                return new GreetingCardImpl();
            case ANOTHER_HI:
                return new AnotherGreetingCardImpl();
            default:
                return new GreetingCardImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tested that? As you should have AmbiguousResolutionException as GreetingCard can be created in 3 places (2 classes and producer method). See this link about issues related to Produces   http://stackoverflow.com/q/22982422/3701228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why in getGreedingCard() method, it needs a @Produces
>   annotation at all, since the two classes GreetingCardImpl and
>   AnotherGreetingCardImpl are already imported into the space.

Well, it's not that getGreetingCard needs the @Produces annotation. The point is to enable *other* classes to recieve GreetingCards via Dependency Injection.

```
public class Foo {

@Inject // <--- will invoke @Producer method
GreetingCard foosGreetingCard

...

}
```

See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e960) for more details:

> A producer method is a method that acts as a source of bean instances.
>   The method declaration itself describes the bean and the container
>   invokes the method to obtain an instance of the bean when no instance
>   exists in the specified context.

Comment: In the link you gave, Jan, "We can't write a bean class that is itself a random number. But we can certainly write a method that returns a random number. ". Why can't we write a class that's itself a random number? Any class can be written in a bean form. Right?

Comment: That's kind of an unrelated issue - in SOF in generally appreciated to not use comments for that but to start a new question instead. Otherwise it's getting really hard to read & understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it doesn't need `@Produces` as you will be injecting factory bean and using its method directly to create instances, and not injecting the greetingCard beans themseleves.

```
@Inject
GreetingCardFactory factory;

...

GreetingCard card = factory.getGreetingCard();
```

If you would define it as `@Produces` method, and the try to inject `GreetingCard`, then you would get exception that I've described in the comment.

However, if you would additionally create qualifier, like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ProducedCard {}
```

and add it to the producer method:

```
@Produces @ProducedCard 
public GreetingCard getGreetingCard() {
...
```

then you would be able to inject just `GreetingCard` beans using your producer method like this:

```
@Inject @ProducedCard
GreetingCard card;
```

since now there is no ambiguity, as there is only one place to create greeting cards marked with `@ProducedCard` :-)