# Declare @Inject as concrete implementation of @Produces returned interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, interface, cdi, implementation, producer

Is there any way to inject a concrete implementation of `@Produces` returned interface?

```
SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
    public Integer iField;
}
```

Producer class:

```
@Produces
public SomeClass produceChild(){
    SomeClassImpl impl = new SomeClassImpl();
    impl.iField = 17;
    return impl;
}
```

Consumer class:

```
@Inject SomeClassImpl classImpl;
```

**EDIT**

The attempt to `@Inject SomeClassImpl` doesn't force container to use the `@Produces` method that returns super-type `SomeClass`.

Why it is possible to inject child-type via `@Inject` parent-type (without Producer), but no variants inject child-type via `@Produces` parent-type ?

Comment: Use [qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html) if you have more than one implementation of an interface

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982422/cdi-ambiguous-dependency-with-produces-why).

Comment: In regards to your edit, because your `@Produces` method produces a `SomeClass` instance, not a `SomeClassImpl` instance, which could return any implementation of `SomeClass`, not just `SomeClassImpl` instances. You can fix it by injecting `SomeClass` (not the implementation) and using a qualifier, or by modifying your `@Produces` method to return `SomeClassImpl`.

Comment: I got it, thanks, but i need to inject exactly SomeClassImpl type via Produces method. If its not possible - tell me please "This is not possible!" =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Typed` to control what the valid types are for your bean.  https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html